# Ruby on Rails database variables are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migrate

I'm new to Rails, and I've been working based off of a friend's code: http://pastebin.com/6HwT6CBs

When I try to manipulate a variable (such as accuracy_ratio), Rails throws errors at me. Example:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post]) #These lines work fine
@post.user = current_user
@post.name = @post.user.name

@post.accuracy_ratio = 1.0 #This one throws an error
```

On NetBeans Rails, when I type "@post.", the variables user and name pop up underneath the autocomplete helper, but not accuracy_ratio.

I think this is because I need Rails to reconfigure changes I make to the table. Is this true? If not, does anyone know how I can solve this?

edit: thanks so much guys. as i said, im a ruby scrub. after running rake db:migrate i got it working.

Comment: What is the error? And did you run the migrations?

Comment: As @Zabba points out, you need to run the migrations every time you change a migration file.

Comment: The most important thing I can tell you about asking questions on StackOverflow: Don't tell us you get an error, **show us what error**. We can't help you otherwise. Telling us you "got an error" is a useless statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you sure the type 'double' exists at all? Seems like your migration just failed. Use float or decimal instead(depending on your requirements).

Comment: It should probably be decimal (as the migration data type). Only use floats when you don't care about accuracy, otherwise decimals.

Comment: Fixed the answer to be more generic.

Answer (score 1):

Activerecord will change your model based on what it finds in the database table.  If you have run the migration and the table contains the column, then there is something wrong.  You can reload by "reload!" and check the model to see if it has the new column.

You should load up the console and just type Post to see what fields it has.  I am not too familar with netbeans for Rails.  I use Rubymine and the text console.